# Restoring a Firebird 2.5 database freezes at Committing Metadata in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, firebird

**My OS:** Windows 8.1
**Firebird version:** 2.5.1 (Super server/Classic)

When I try to restore a backup using gbak.exe or using my backup and restore utility that uses ibec_RestoreDatabase, the process freezes at "Committing Metadata" with zero CPU usage.

- Firebird becomes unusable from there onwards, until I restart the service.
- Restore works fine from there onwards, until the machine is restarted again.
- The same gbak command and backup/restore utility works fine in Windows 7, XP & Server 2008.

Backup command:

```
gbak -v -t -user sysdba -password masterkey localhost:<database aliase>  c:\backup1.gbk
```

Restore command:

```
gbak.exe -rep -v -t -user sysdba -password masterkey c:\backup1.gbk localhost:<database aliase>
```

Has any body else come across this situation?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Consider upgrading to Firebird 2.5.3. A lot of bugs have been fixed and improvements have been made since 2.5.1. I don't know if there was a specific change or fix related to this, but you might want to check the [releasenotes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes253.html). Just know that you need to backup and restore, or rebuild the indexes due to a incompatible change between 2.5.1 and 2.5.2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that as well. But didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Just some additional information: OS is Windows 8.1 64bit and Upgraded the 32bit Firebird 2.5.3, without success. I use 32bit Firebird as I have some 32 bit UDFs. There's no issue when doing the same process in 64bit Windows 7.

Comment: What will happen if you'll make backup on win8.1 and try to restore on win7?

Comment: It restores successfully. Today, one of our guys noticed this happening if you do a backup and a restore right after a reboot. But if you do a restore right after a reboot it works fine. Strange but we are looking for patterns right now.

Comment: Noticed that one of our 32bit UDFs is using ShellExecuteEx() and it hangs there. Fixed the DLL file and all working fine. Looks like restore reads all the DLL file during commit. BUT, restore works fine if I delete the DLL file(s) used for the custom UDFs as well. Is Firebird reading the DLL files unnecessarily? If not how can the Restore work fine without them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling "System restore" in Windows ? If this works, your database file may have a .GDB extension. Change it to something else like .FDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
gbak.exe -rep -v -t **-user sysdba -password masterkey** c:\backup1.gbk localhost:<database aliase>
```

don´t use `-user sysdba - password masterkey`. It´s not necessary.